# Is it possible to change the FeedItem actor from active user to name of flow?

Tags: feeditem, history-tracking, chatter-feed-tracking, casefeed

Currently we have tracking turned on for our cases.  The Case Feed is tracking account, status, contact, and other such fields.  However, the actor of every feed item is always set to the current user. I was wondering if it's possible to change the entry so instead of recording the current user it displays the flow or method that made the change.

For instance:
We have a flow that changes the owner of a case automatically based off different criteria (we don't use assignment rules due to the complexity of our environmental needs).  When this change is completed a feed item automatically shows up as:

> Teejay has changed Case Owner from Teejay to L1 Queue

Is there a way to change this (without creating a new user) so it's displayed along the lines of:

> caseRouting.apxc has change Case Owner to L1 Queue 
>  Case Owner changed to L1 Queue by Case Routing Logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may remove the Chatter Feed tracking for the field and then in the flow add an Action **[Post to Chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_action_feed.htm&language=en_US)** when the owner changes with the exact message that you want to display in the feed.

Basically, you are displaying your own feed item here instead of the standard feed tracking for the field provided by Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So essentially it's just turning off the built-in feed tracking and replacing it with code that does it when it makes the update?

Comment: That's right! @Teejay